# Running GraphQL mutation (Apollo) server side via node js script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-apollo, prisma-graphql

I am running a scraping script (Puppeteer), and would like to write each scraped row to the database.

I'm currently getting this error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'
import $ from 'cheerio'
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import moment from 'moment'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const ADD_RESULT = gql`
  mutation CreateOneResult( $site: String!, $status: String!, $link: String!, $name: String, $publication: String, $decision: String, $clause: String, $commentText: String, $decisionText: String, $noDateReceived: Boolean, $dateReceived: DateTime, $noDateConcluded: Boolean, $dateConcluded: DateTime! ) {
    createOneResult(data: {
        site: $site,
        status: $status,
        link: $link,
        name: $name,
        publication: $publication,
        decision: $decision,
        clause: $clause,
        commentText: $commentText,
        decisionText: $decisionText,
        noDateReceived: $noDateReceived,
        dateReceived: $dateReceived,
        noDateConcluded: $noDateConcluded,
        dateConcluded: $dateConcluded,
    }){
        id
    }
  }
`

/**
 * Loop results and follow the link, scraping extra info
 */
export async function doExtraScrapeStepsAndAddToDB(results) {

    results = await (async () => {
        var updatedResults = []
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            let result = results[i]
            let extraResultInfo = await module.exports.getExtraPageInfoFromLink(result)

            if (extraResultInfo) {
                let updatedResultInfo = { ...result, ...extraResultInfo }
                let added = await addResultToDB(updatedResultInfo)
                console.log(`Added result of ID ${added} to the database`)
                updatedResults.push(updatedResultInfo)
            }
        }
        return updatedResults
    })()

    return results
}

/**
 * Add result to DB
 */
export async function addResultToDB(result) {
    const [CreateOneResult] = useMutation(ADD_RESULT)

    return await CreateOneResult({
        variables: {
            ...result,
            ...(false == result.noDateConcluded && {
                dateReceived: moment(result.dateConcluded, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format(moment.HTML5_FMT.DATETIME_LOCAL_SECONDS)
            }),
            ...(false == result.noDateReceived && {
                dateReceived: moment(result.dateReceived, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format(moment.HTML5_FMT.DATETIME_LOCAL_SECONDS)
            }),
        }
    })
}
```

- `doExtraScrapeStepsAndAddToDB` is called
- It grabs some further information for each result (from another URL) via `getExtraPageInfoFromLink`
- Finally, the completed result is written to the DB via `addResultToDB`

I am planning to use GraphQL (Apollo) on the front end, so thought I could practise by writing to the DB with GraphQL mutations on the back-end, in this scraping script.

I don't really understand the nature of the error other than the `useMutation` function only being able to be used in a function component(?). If that is the case, what would be an alternative here?

I am using:

- GraphQL
- Nexus
- Prisma
- Apollo

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'

const client = new ApolloClient({
        link: createHttpLink({
            uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/graphql',
            fetch: fetch
        }),
        cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });

return await client.mutate({
        mutation: ADD_RESULT,
        variables: {
            ...result,
            ...(false == result.noDateConcluded && {
                dateReceived: moment(result.dateConcluded, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format(moment.HTML5_FMT.DATETIME_LOCAL_SECONDS)
            }),
            ...(false == result.noDateReceived && {
                dateReceived: moment(result.dateReceived, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format(moment.HTML5_FMT.DATETIME_LOCAL_SECONDS)
            }),
        }
    })
```